# Automount of USB memory devices in VT

Tags: usb, automount, virtual-console, udisks

It seems that when in a DE inside X automount works properly. When instead I'm in a virtual terminal (even with X running in another), there is no automount working. When I plug the device nothing is mounted. However, if I go to X I see a authentication dialog asking for the password. Action is "Mount a filesystem" and vendor is "The udisks Project". If I enter the password one partition is mounted.

Is it possible to enable automount for the entire system, independently on the X and/or DE running?

I tried usbmount and it seems to work, but I need dbus events coming from udisks2 (org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem), and that is not generating those it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't enable automount when not in the DE. I had to do it myself in C using dbus and udisks. I followed something similar to https://github.com/Razor-qt/razor-qt.